# How to get Aborted user name in jenkins using env varibale

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want mail notification with **user name** if that build was abort by any user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following plugins

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mailer

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin

You can configure based on your requirements whom you want to send the email and when you want to send the email.

Once installed you can configure the setting in post-build action

You also need to "Set Jenkins user build variables" in Build Environment section so that you can use all Jenkins default variables.

Hope it helps.